# PHP Two lines read from file and put to variables

Tags: php, lines

I have now PCB file with folowing syntax:

```
PAD EL 81 81 23 AL NP "" 1124 3836 0 0 0
PAD EL 81 81 23 AL NP "" 1524 3836 0 0 0
PAD EL 81 81 23 AL NP "" 1524 3684 0 0 0
PAD EL 81 81 23 AL NP "" 1924 3684 0 0 0
PAD EL 81 81 23 AL NP "" 3324 3838 0 0 0
PAD EL 81 81 23 AL NP "" 3724 3838 0 0 0
```

Now i need to get numbers into variables, i need to get:

```
X1=1124   Y1=3836
X2=1524   Y2=3836
X3=1524   Y3=3684
X4=1924   Y4=3684
```

So that i can get distance for components using $IsResistorVeritcal=X4-X3=400 or $IsResistorHorizontal=X2-X1=400.

My knowledge of PHP is not great, so i im needing your help.

Thanks.

This is code that extract x coordinates using every odd or oven number...little progress:)

```
/* Open File */
$fp = fopen($fileName, "r");

/* Read File */
while (!feof($fp))
{
    /* read one line */
    $line = fgets($fp);

    /* if is pad */
    if (strpos($line,'PAD') !== false)
    {
        $ps = explode('" ', $line);

        $points = array();

        foreach($ps as $point){
            $exploded =  explode(" ", $point);
            $points["x".$i] = $exploded[0];
            $points["y".$i] = $exploded[1];
            $i++;
        }

        $i=$i-1;
        if ($i % 2 == 0)
        {
            echo 'x'.$i.' = '.$points["x".$i].'<br/>';
        } else {
            echo 'x'.$i.' = '.$points["x".$i].'<br/>';
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should start with [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

This way you can read your file, and then split the contents into an array (new line and space).

e.g.

```
$sContent = file_get_contents($sFile);
$aContent = explode("\n\r", $sContent); //or just "\n"
print_r($aContent);
```

Comment: /* Read File */
 while (!feof($fp))
 {
  /* read one line */
  $line = fgets($fp);
  
  /* if is pad */
  if (strpos($line,'PAD') !== false)
  {
   $ps = explode('" ', $line);

   $points = array();
   
   foreach($ps as $point){
    $exploded =  explode(" ", $point);
    $points["x".$i] = $exploded[0];
    $points["y".$i] = $exploded[1];
    $i++;
   }
   
   print_r($points);
    
   
  }
 }      but it reads only first line and x1 is ovveriden with last line value...so it don't works.

Comment: Pls don't write you code into comments like this. Change your post with the edit button (better to read).

Comment: Ok...Thank You for helping me out...now have posted a function that reads x cordinates...i im now testing code...to be fully functional.Thank YOu for help.